# CentOS 5.8 Server, manual install PHP 5.2.17

Tags: installation, php, centos, apache-http-server

I would like manually install PHP 5.2.17.
I manage to install httpd and mysql.

But when I want to PHP 5.2.17, I could not found a proper guide.
These the step I had done with a fresh installation of CentOS 5.8 x86_64 (server & server GUI)

1. `yum install httpd httpd-devel`
2. `/etc/init.d start` OK
3. `/etc/init.d stop` OK
4. `yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel`
5. `yum remove php`
6. `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`
7. `yum install libxml2-devel`
8. `wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2` to get php5.2.17 (client requirement must use this version)
9. `cd php5.2.17`
10. `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql=/usr/local`

This is the area I confuse.

I could not found the `/usr/sbin/apxs` in my system. I do another Google search on how to manually install PHP, they pointed using `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql`

Both localtion I also cannot find apxs or apache2. I scare I make any mistake on it. Please help and guide on this.

I am newbie in CentOS

Comment: The wget url no longer works this one does `wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after few days research on this topic. I do know the parameter for what.
That is the specify directory would like to install to it.

That's the reason I can't find the path is created.

For best practise, it good to do it like this way

if you prefer install inside apache folder

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache/php
```

or

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php
```

Comment: folks should also pass --enable-force-cgi-redirect to configure which will silence a security warning when building the code